# how to retrieve all keys with a given value from dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures

I want to get the list of keys of dictionary for a given value. For example

```
my_dict = {1: 2, 3: 3, 4: 2}
value = 2
```

I want to get 1 and 4.

How to get the list of correspondent keys?

Comment: What have you tried? This is relatively easy to do without additional libraries and a simple `list` comprehension.

Comment: The dictionary is make for lookups in the other direction. If you have to lookup value -> key often you should revise your data structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using list comprehension you can filter per values as well as per keys:

```
given_value = 2
keys_list = [k for k, v in my_dict.items() if v == given_value]  # [1, 4]
```

Or using Python built-in `filter`:

```
given_value = 2
keys_iter = filter(lambda k: my_dict[k] == given_value, my_dict.keys()) # return an iterator
keys_list = list(keys_iter)
```

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension can do that in linear time - if you need that once.
If your design needs for alternating retrieving `keys -> values` and `values->keys mappings`, them you can design your own class or by using a library.

My own Python's [Extradict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/extradict/0.2.5) has the `BijectiveDict` class that does exactly that, trying to be as direct as possible.

But note that you need to further specify your desired behavior there - in your example, the value `2` is associated with 2 keys. BijectiveDict's default behavior is to simply overwrite the earlier assignments: you jsut retrieve the latest key bound to a certain value.